# Identityserver : force user sign out from server without user interaction?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a requirment in which I have to sign out some user to which a jwt was emitted, but without the user having to know about this (so somehow to invalidate a token or to force the user to login again)

Following is the scenario. Say I am assigned some roles and I sign in into the system and the system generates a jwt for me to which it attaches my roles, but does not keep any reference to it anywhere or any other mechanism to identify it. The token is dealt and that is it.
Now a 2nd user that has admin rights can go ahead and remove some of the roles that I have, but since I already have a valid token I can still use it till it expires and still can get accees according to old roles list to parts of the system that I shouldn't have rights to access.

This is my issue, the requirment is to not keep any reference to identify a token in the system, so I have no idea how can I overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> This is my issue, the requirment is to not keep any reference to
> identify a token in the system, so I have no idea how can I overcome
> this issue.

And if IdentityServer4 do it for you? Would meet the requirements?

You could configure your clients to use [reference tokens](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html?highlight=reference%20tokens). The problem with this is that you add an extra call from the Api to IS4 (instrospection) to get the actual token, but you could revoke users without any problem.

> When using reference tokens - IdentityServer will store the contents
> of the token in a data store and will only issue a unique identifier
> for this token back to the client. The API receiving this reference
> must then open a back-channel communication to IdentityServer to
> validate the token.

You'll need Api credentials (Api Name + Api Secret) to call introspection endpoint by using a compatible handler.